# Orchard binding tab is empty in custom forms

Tags: forms, binding, field, orchardcms

I am very new to orchard. I added two text fields for users (first & last name) which I couldn't see under fields in content-definition user setting! Then I made a custom form. When I tried to set binding I saw binding tab is empty! Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you have to save the form and then go back in some situations?

Comment: is it an answer or a question? :D I tried that but nothing changed. thank you anyway.

Comment: probably should have been a comment, I was just taking a shot in the dark